# Warning with soapcpp2.exe compilation in gSoap

Tags: warnings, deserialization, gsoap

This is what i have got on cmd after run WSservice.h header file with soapcpp2.exe

```
C:\Users\Tushar\Desktop\zzzzz>soapcpp2 -i -C -I C:\Users\Tushar\Desktop\gsoap_2.
8.22\gsoap-2.8\gsoap\import WSservice.h

**  The gSOAP code generator for C and C++, soapcpp2 release 2.8.22
**  Copyright (C) 2000-2015, Robert van Engelen, Genivia Inc.
**  All Rights Reserved. This product is provided "as is", without any warranty.

**  The soapcpp2 tool is released under one of the following licenses:
**  GPL or the commercial license by Genivia Inc.


WSservice.h(3525): *WARNING*: identifier 'ns2__UserConfigurationPropertyType__Xm
lData' starts with or embeds 'Xml' character sequence exclusively reserved for t
he XML standard (for enum constants: please ignore this warning)


WSservice.h(7290): *WARNING*: template type 'std::vector<xsd__base64Binary>' of
attachment objects may lead to deserialization failures, use 'std::vector<*xsd__
base64Binary>' instead


WSservice.h(12370): *WARNING*: template type 'std::vector<xsd__base64Binary>' of
 attachment objects may lead to deserialization failures, use 'std::vector<*xsd_
_base64Binary>' instead


WSservice.h(14544): *WARNING*: identifier 'XmlData' starts with or embeds 'Xml'
character sequence exclusively reserved for the XML standard (for enum constants
: please ignore this warning)


WSservice.h(24953): *WARNING*: identifier 'Xml' starts with or embeds 'Xml' char
acter sequence exclusively reserved for the XML standard (for enum constants: pl
ease ignore this warning)

Saving soapStub.h annotated copy of the source input
Saving soapH.h declarations to #include
Using ns1 service name: ExchangeServiceBinding
Using ns1 service style: document
Using ns1 service encoding: literal
Using ns1 service location: http://localhost:80
Using ns1 schema namespace: http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/
messages
Saving soapExchangeServiceBindingProxy.h client proxy class
Saving soapExchangeServiceBindingProxy.cpp client proxy class
........
....
...
..// here the list of all generated proxy and xml files are saving.
..
...
.....
Compilation successful (5 warnings)
```

so after edit for 2nd and 3rd warning in header file and re-run the soapcpp2 i've following error, why?

```
    C:\Users\Tushar\Desktop\test>soapcpp2 -j -C -I C:\Users\Tushar\Desktop\gsoap_2.8
.22\gsoap-2.8\gsoap\import WSservice.h

**  The gSOAP code generator for C and C++, soapcpp2 release 2.8.22
**  Copyright (C) 2000-2015, Robert van Engelen, Genivia Inc.
**  All Rights Reserved. This product is provided "as is", without any warranty.

**  The soapcpp2 tool is released under one of the following licenses:
**  GPL or the commercial license by Genivia Inc.


WSservice.h(3525): *WARNING*: identifier 'ns2__UserConfigurationPropertyType__Xm
lData' starts with or embeds 'Xml' character sequence exclusively reserved for t
he XML standard (for enum constants: please ignore this warning)

WSservice.h(7290): syntax error
WSservice.h(7289): Syntax error: declaration expected
WSservice.h(7292): syntax error
WSservice.h(7291): Syntax error: declaration expected
WSservice.h(12370): syntax error
WSservice.h(12369): Syntax error: declaration expected
WSservice.h(12372): syntax error
WSservice.h(12371): Syntax error: declaration expected

WSservice.h(14544): *WARNING*: identifier 'XmlData' starts with or embeds 'Xml'
character sequence exclusively reserved for the XML standard (for enum constants
: please ignore this warning)


WSservice.h(24953): *WARNING*: identifier 'Xml' starts with or embeds 'Xml' char
acter sequence exclusively reserved for the XML standard (for enum constants: pl
ease ignore this warning)

Saving soapStub.h annotated copy of the source input
Saving soapH.h declarations to #include
Using ns1 service name: ExchangeServiceBinding
Using ns1 service style: document
Using ns1 service encoding: literal
Using ns1 service location: http://localhost:80
Using ns1 schema namespace: http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/
messages
Saving soapExchangeServiceBindingProxy.h client proxy class
Saving soapExchangeServiceBindingProxy.cpp client proxy class
Saving ExchangeServiceBinding.ResolveNames.req.xml sample SOAP/XML request
Saving ExchangeServiceBinding.ResolveNames.res.xml sample SOAP/XML response
Saving ExchangeServiceBinding.ExpandDL.req.xml sample SOAP/XML request
Saving ExchangeServiceBinding.ExpandDL.res.xml sample SOAP/XML response
........
....
...
..// here the list of all generated proxy and xml files are saving.
..
...
.....   
There were errors:
4 syntax errors
3 warnings
```

what if i ignore all the previous 5 warnings, so does those 5 warning will be create a problem with the development of web services if i ignore them?

Please please help me. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/services.wsdl this was my wsdl file source.

Comment: first, forth and fifth warning could be ignore, but what about second and third warning  for deserialization failures? please give me any idea. thanks.